# ng2-bootstrap tooltip content line break at a certain position

Tags: ng2-bootstrap

How do I put line break especially between {{UpdateTime}} and {{RawValue}} in ng2-bootstrap tooltip?

html:

```
<span tooltipPlacement="bottom" tooltipClass="customClass" tooltip="{{UpdateTime}} {{RawValue}}">{{DisplayName }}</span>
```

css:

```
.tooltip.customClass .tooltip-inner {
    -ms-word-break:  break-word;
    word-break:  break-word;       
    text-align: center;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
}
```

It breaks within the tooltip box, but not in the right place, I need to have a line break right after {{UpdateTime}}, align in two lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of (at least) 1.3.3 tooltipHtml no longer works. Instead use a template reference.

```
<template #statusTemplate>
    lorem ipsum <br /> dolor sit amet
</template> 
<div....
    [tooltip]="statusTemplate"
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost correct. It has to be a `ng-template` tag and not `template`. (v5.6.0+)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Use tooltipHtml property instead of tooltip, and insert `<br/>`  between the two values will do!